# Finding $f^{(2015)}(0,0,0)(x,y,z)^{2015}$ if $f=xe^{1-xy}+ \frac{z}{1-z^2}+z^{3}\sin(x+y).$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion

$$f^{(2015)}(0,0,0)(x,y,z)^{2015}$$

$$f=xe^{1-xy}+ \frac{z}{1-z^2}+z^{3}\sin(x+y).$$

I will give you my thoughts as soon as I type out an example from class that makes sense to me. Use of Taylor series:

$f^{(2014)}(0,0,0)(x,y,z)^{2014}=? \ \ \ \ f(x,y,z)=e^{x}+ \sin{(xz)}+\frac{1}{1-yz}$

The Maclaurin series of functions: $ e^x , \sin(x), \frac{1}{1-x}$ are used:

$$f((x,y,z))=
\sum_{n=0}^{+ \infty}{\frac{x^n}{n!}}
+ 
\sum_{n=0}^{+ \infty}{(-1)^n\frac{(xz)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}}
+ 
\sum_{n=0}^{+ \infty}{(yz)^{n}}=... \\ 
\frac{f^{(2014)}(0,0,0)(x,y,z)^{2014}}{2014!}=...+\frac{x^{2014}}{(2014)!}+\frac{(-1)^{503}(xz)^{1007}}{1007!}+(yz)^{1007} \\ \implies
f^{(2014)}(0)h^{2014}=2014!(\frac{x^{2014}}{(2014)!}+\frac{(-1)^{503}(xz)^{1007}}{1007!}+(yz)^{1007}) 
$$

(Im guessing the logic is that the monoms need to be of degree 2014), but it's different with my question, because you have multipliers like $x, z, z^3$. Anyone have an idea on this one ?

Now the expression in question comes from $$f(x+h)-f(x)= f'(x)h + \frac{f''(x)h^2}{2!}+...+ \frac{f^{(2015)}(x)h^{2015}}{2015!}+....$$

Comment: What is $f^{2015}(0,0,0)(x,y,z)^{2015}$ supposed to mean?

Comment: I also do not understand. Is this the 2015th derivative? What is the 2015 at the end?

Comment: Yes, this is the 2015 derivative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.**

You have $$f_1(x,y,z)=xe^{1-xy}=xee^{-xy}=x\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} (-1)^k \frac{(xy)^k}{k!}$$ Considering the multiplication by $x$, you'll get a term of power $2015$ if and only if $2k+1=2015$, hence $k=1007$. I said $2k+1$ as you have one $k$ for $x$ and another one for $y$ in $(xy)^k$ and $+1$ for the "standalone" $x$ multiplication.

$$f_2(x,y,z)=\frac{z}{1-z^2}=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} z^{2k+1}$$ To get a term of power $2015$, the only option is $2k+1=2015$ hence $k=1007$ Finally
$$f_3(x,y,z)=z^3 \sin(x+y)=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} (-1)^k \frac{z^3(x+y)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$$ Here, you'll get terms of power $2015$ for $2k+1+3=2015$ which is not possible. So you won't get term of degree $2015$ from $f_3$.